# Help with nHibernate design/ mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a pretty simple data model.

Article (ID, name, body, date)
Category (ID, name, count)

Article_Category (articleID, categoryID)

Comment (ID, articleID, name, body, date)

How would I go about laying out my nhibernate mapping?

Also, when I create a new article, it will only have the article and the ID of the category to associate it to.  How would it persist to the database in this scenerio?

Answer (score 1):

For the Article and Category example you need to check out many-to-many mapping and load vs. get.

Many-to-many (6.1 to 6.3 in documentation):

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues

load (9.2 in documentation):

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading

For comment it sounds like a simple one-to-many would work, and a good reading of chapter 6 would help.